# I am confused how to compile this program in my system?

Tags: java

I have tried all the possible ways whichever you have provided in this website, but still unable to compile successfully. Please help me

```
import java.util.*;
    class Test1 
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "test";
        }
        public static void main(String\[\] args) 
        {
            String s = new String("Raja");
            System.out.println(s);
            Integer I = new Integer(10);
            System.out.println(I);
            ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
            l.add("A");
            l.add("B");
            System.out.println(l);
            Test1 t  = new Test1();
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting error:
[image: Picture]

Comment: There is no compiler provided by this site. I have no idea what you're talking about. Have you tried just Googling "how to compile java"? Try ideone.com: http://ideone.com/buq2yg

Comment: Read the compile errors carefully, and take the necessary actions as descried.

Comment: actually i want to say that whatever posts are their related to compilation problem, I have tried those commands but compilation is not getting success. Is there any other way to compile it?

Comment: Have you used your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test1 
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "test";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = new String("Raja");
        System.out.println(s);
        Integer I = new Integer(10);
        System.out.println(I);
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("A");
        l.add("B");
        System.out.println(l);
        Test1 t  = new Test1();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

javac Test1
java Test1

Comment: Please add English to explain how your code addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles, actually.

The message you are concerned of is only a warning, in particular about this line:

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
```

Here you are declaring an `ArrayList` withouth providing a generic type. For more information about generics see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).